# What architecture could be suitable for a secure environment?

Tags: hardware, kernel

According to [these slides on replacing UEFI with Linux](https://schd.ws/hosted_files/osseu17/84/Replace%20UEFI%20with%20Linux.pdf):

> Between Linux and the hardware are at least 2 ½ kernels.

Are there any architectures that contain fewer layers between the main OS and the HW itself?

Comment: Although you want the answers for the purposes of security, the question itself is not a security question. To answer your question: yes, it's called firmware ... What you *want* to ask is what *user-level operating systems with a UI* have more direct access to hardware.

Comment: Not sure that this is a well defined question: you can directly program an Arduino, for example, but it doesn't really have an OS in the Linux/Windows model. Are you after general purpose devices? Systems that run specific software? A dedicated device? How about a router running iOS?

Comment: you are also making an assumption that "fewer layers" translated into increased security

Answer (score 2):

In short yes.

The 2.5 kernels the linked paper talks of are built into the processor and motherboard firmware. Specifically newer Intel processors on UEFI based boards.

There are endless devices that will happily run linux on far simpler boards. Most ARM based setups will have notably less between the OS and the hardware. A Raspberry Pi is an easy to point to example - although there is still a layer of firmware on the chip. There are also entirely open sourced boards like [the beagle board](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BeagleBoard). And then you have the option to simply go for older hardware.

However as @schroeder points out in the comments why would fewer layers translate to better security? If you don't trust the hardware manufacturer then how do you know that there isn't an additional hypervisor hidden deep within the chip? - especially seeing as most modern x86 processors have huge numbers of transistors which are never or extremely rarely used in normal operation.

If your security requirements drop to not trusting Intel/AMD then this is one of the simpler aspects you need to consider.